# Unable to run repacked spring boot jar caused by "Unable to open nested entry"

Tags: spring-boot

I am setting up a build pipeline for a spring boot project.

It has three stages so far:

```
build: compile-->unit test-->archive the jar
deploy acceptance test: repack the jar for acc environment (replacing datasource.properties etc)
deploy uat test: repack the jar for uat environment (replacing datasource.properties etc)
```

I don't want to build the jar from scratch for different environments as it wastes time and potentially has risk of building inconsistent artifacts.
For traditional war project, I just extract the war, replace the config files and repack. But this time with spring boot, somehow it does not work. When I run the repacked jar, it reports

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
```

I extracted the origin jar and the repacked jar and don't find differences with lib folder.

```
task extractArtifact() {
    doLast {

        def outputDirName = "${buildDir}/tmp/under_config"
        def outputDir = file(outputDirName)
        assert outputDir.deleteDir()  // cleanup workspace

        def zipFile = file("${buildDir}/libs/${getArtifactName()}")

        copy {
            from zipTree(zipFile)
            into outputDir
        }

        copy {
            from file("${buildDir}/env")
            into file("${buildDir}/tmp/under_config")
        }

    }
}

task repackConfiguredArtifact(type: Zip, dependsOn: extractArtifact)  {
    archiveName = "${getArtifactName()}"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/libs/${getEnv()}")
    from file("${buildDir}/tmp/under_config")
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Or how do you guys config the jar for different environment (without re-compile the binary).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What does "config the jar" mean?

Comment: Replacing configuration files inside the jar for different environments. The configuration files, for example, like datasource.properties etc

Comment: I would always externalise property files. Not an answer to your primary question, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: Thank you, @ci_ . It is good solution indeed, but there is some constraints in this project keep us from this approach.

Answer (score 16):

You shoud add -0 to store only; use no ZIP compression

```
$jar -cvf0m yourproject.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
```

There is another soulution:
[Set the active Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)

```
$java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can use application-${profile}.properties to specify profile-specific values.

Comment: This has worked for me:
I CD into the folder where I have the spring boot exploded, and then
`jar cMvf0 attachment-module-fat.jar *`

Comment: Thank you @razvang. What you mentioned worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution after looking up the spring-boot reference.

1. turn default spring boot repackage off since I need to repack it anyway.
2. extract the traditional jar and copy the config files
3. Use jar type task to repack it
4. Use BootRepackage type task to assemble a spring-boot jar.

here is the code:

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}

task extractArtifact() {
    doLast {

        def outputDirName = "${buildDir}/tmp/under_config"
        def outputDir = file(outputDirName)
        assert outputDir.deleteDir()  // cleanup workspace

        def zipFile = file("${buildDir}/libs/${getArtifactName()}")

        copy {
            from zipTree(zipFile)
            into outputDir
        }

        copy {
            from file("${buildDir}/env")
            into file("${buildDir}/tmp/under_config")
        }

        assert zipFile.delete()
    }
}

task clientJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: extractArtifact) {
    archiveName = "${getArtifactName()}"
    from file("${buildDir}/tmp/under_config")
}

task repackConfiguredArtifact(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn: clientJar) {
    withJarTask = clientJar
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that if you had a directory called 'resources/lib' the spring-boot executable JAR would assume the contents were zipped and throw the above exception. Renaming to 'resources/static' worked for me.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question